# How get I the bin size of plotly.express histogram?

Tags: python, plotly, histogram, plotly-python

I want to have the bin size of the plotly histogram.
I plot my histogram like this and want to mark the x-axis with the bins size:

```
fig = px.histogram(df_de["len_job_task"], histnorm='probability density')
bin_edges = fig['data'][0]['xbins']['end']
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickmode='array', tickvals=bin_edges))
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='black', marker_line_width=1)
fig.show()
```

[image]

But it doesn't work. I would like it like below with matplotlib - there I set the number of bins and get the bins and set them to the x-axis

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(df_de["len_job_task"], bins=20, edgecolor='black')
plt.xticks(bins[::2])
plt.xlabel("Bins")
plt.ylabel("Length")
```

[image]

How can do I with plotly?

Answer (score 0):

Any number of bins can be set by setting xbins. See here for an [example](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#choosing-the-number-of-bins). An [example](https://plotly.com/python/histograms/#accessing-the-counts-yaxis-values) of how to customize the number of bins can be found here. You can also get the start, end, and steps of the bins automatically created by express and use them as the new x-axis scale. This functionality is provided for development purposes.

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

df = px.data.tips()

fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", histnorm='probability density')
#bin_edges = fig['data'][0]['xbins']['end']
#fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickmode='array', tickvals=bin_edges))
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='black', marker_line_width=1)

full_fig = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
range_dict = full_fig['data'][0]['xbins']
fig.update_xaxes(tickvals=np.arange(range_dict.start, range_dict.end+range_dict.size, range_dict.size))
                 
fig.show()
```

[image]